# Why I can't remove directory using mv?

Tags: shell, init.d

So I want to use `bindfs` that require the mounted directory to be empty. Then I'm trying to move WhatsApp (Internal storage) contents to external SD card

```
sdcard="/mnt/media_rw/6DE8-1BC6/"
mv /data/media/0/WhatsApp/* /data/media/0/WhatsApp/.* $sdcard/WhatsApp/
```

But then `mv` outputting this

```
mv: can't remove '/data/media/0/WhatsApp/.Shared': Is a directory
mv: can't remove '/data/media/0/WhatsApp/.StickerThumbs': Is a directory
mv: can't remove '/data/media/0/WhatsApp/.Thumbs': Is a directory
mv: can't remove '/data/media/0/WhatsApp/.trash': Is a directory
mv: can't remove '/data/media/0/WhatsApp/Backups': Is a directory
mv: can't remove '/data/media/0/WhatsApp/Databases': Is a directory
mv: can't remove '/data/media/0/WhatsApp/Media': Is a directory
```

What is happening here?

Maybe I should use this instead?

```
cp -r /data/media/0/WhatsApp/* $sdcard/WhatsApp/
cp -r /data/media/0/WhatsApp/.* $sdcard/WhatsApp/
rm -rf /data/media/0/WhatsApp/
```

I'm running this using `init.d`

Comment: instead of copy you can create hard links with `cp -al` (if *$sdcard* is on same file system). another method is piping two tar commands 
together https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/127712

Comment: I don't think `fat` filesystem support links. How I pipe tar?

Comment: `tar : Unknown option Bf` :(

Comment: *'tar -c /sdcard/WhatsApp | tar -xC $sdcard && find /sdcard/WhatsApp -mindepth 1 -delete'*